# Downgrade Perl Version 5.16.3 on RedHat 7 to 5.10.1

Tags: perl

I'm making a migration of my monitoring application from a redhat 6 server to a redhat 7 server.  There are perl plugins I have on the redhat 6 server that work.  But when migrated to redhat 7, they dont.

The package in question here is **perl-DBD-Sybase.x86_64      1.10-1.el6.rf**

Im able to install this package on redhat 7 (there doesnt appear to be a redhat 7 version of it - at least, i havent found one).

And when I install the package and try to use the plugin that uses the package, I get the following error:

```
[/usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/DBD/Sybase/Sybase.so: undefined symbol: Perl_Istack_sp_ptr]
```

Do i have any other alternative to dealing with this?  how can i resolve this so it works on redhat 7?

Comment: Did you read this answer? It might help you.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6256755/7499402

Answer (score 0):

You can also setup Perlbrew. That will give you the opportunity to run your scripts in any possible Perl version while leaving your system Perl untouched.